# jsTree search only in "files" or "folder" titles

Tags: search, jstree

I have a 2-layer jsTree. First layer is "folders". Second layer is "files". Is it possible to search only in file titles or in folder titles? Not in the whole jstree.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can do it using standard [jsTree search plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/search)

Good news that you can [write your own search function](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/10). Here is an excerpt. It shows demonstrates using a custom function to search for multiple words separated by spaces:

> I needed to search for multiple words separated by spaces so I give
>   you my function to add to search plugin (currently the search engine
>   plugin only search for one word).
>
> ```
> /*
>  * jsTree search plugin
>  * Enables both sync and async search on the tree
>  * DOES NOT WORK WITH JSON PROGRESSIVE RENDER
>  */
> (function ($) {
>
>     $.expr[':'].jstree_contains_multi = function(a,i,m){
>
>         var word, words = [];
>         var searchFor = m[3].toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+/g,'').replace(/\s+$/g,'');
>         if(searchFor.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
>             words = searchFor.split(' ');
>         }
>         else {
>             words = [searchFor];
>         }
>         for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
>             word = words[i];
>             if((a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(word) >= 0) {
>                 return true;
>             }
>         }
>         return false;
>
>     };
>
>     $.expr[':'].jstree_contains = function(a,i,m){
>
>         return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase())>=0;
>
>     };
> ```